# OpenCV Mat class: Accessing elements of a multi-channel matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix

I currently want to read in some values into a 3-channel, 480 row by 640 column matrix of 8 bit unsigned integer values.  I am initializing the matrix like this:

Declaration:

```
rgbMatrix = Mat::zeros(480,640,CV_8UC3);
```

When I try to iterate through the entire matrix I am unable to assign/grab values using the following method.  The values simply stay 0.  My code looks like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbMatrix.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rgbMatrix.cols; j++)
        {
           (rgbMatrix.data + rgbMatrix.step * i)[j * rgbMatrix.channels() + 0] = *value0*;
           (rgbMatrix.data + rgbMatrix.step * i)[j * rgbMatrix.channels() + 1] = *value1*;
           (rgbMatrix.data + rgbMatrix.step * i)[j * rgbMatrix.channels() + 2] = *value2*;

        }
     }
```

However, when I declare three separate 1-channel matrices (also 480 row by 640 column of 8 bit unsigned integer values) and attempt to access elements of those matrices the following code works:

Declaration:

```
rgbMatrix0 = Mat::zeros(480,640,CV_8UC1);
rgbMatrix1 = Mat::zeros(480,640,CV_8UC1);
rgbMatrix2 = Mat::zeros(480,640,CV_8UC1);

    for (int i = 0; i < rgbMatrix0.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rgbMatrix0.cols; j++)
        {
           (rgbMatrix0.data + rgbMatrix0.step * i)[j] = *value0*;
           (rgbMatrix1.data + rgbMatrix1.step * i)[j] = *value1*;
           (rgbMatrix2.data + rgbMatrix2.step * i)[j] = *value2*;

        }
     }
```

Now, I want to use just one matrix for these operations, as having to keep track of three separate variables will get tiresome after a while.  I have a feeling that I am not accessing the right point in memory for the three-channel matrix.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish what I did in the second portion of code but using one three-channel matrix instead of three separate one-channel matrices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of ways to do it, for example:

```
cv::Mat rgbMatrix(480,640,CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < rgbMatrix.rows; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < rgbMatrix.cols; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
      rgbMatrix.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k] = value;
```

[k] here is the channel value.

To set the all the matrix elements to a specific value like 5 for example you can do this:

```
cv::Mat rgbMatrix2(cv::Size(480,640), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(5,5,5));
std::cout << rgbMatrix2 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I can't see your code since I am writing from iPhone. When you use 3 channel matrix you can get the pixel using:

Vec3b pix = rgbMatrix.at(row,col);

Now you can access channel using:
pix[0] = 255; pix[1] += pix[2];

P.s. Generally rgbMatrix pixel is of type vec3b or vec3d. Always cast image.at<> with relevant type

Answer (score 3):

Very Simple using Vec3b - for uchar, Vec3i - for int, Vec3f - for float, Vec3d - for double

```
Mat rgbMatrix = Mat::zeros(480,640,CV_8UC1);


for (int i = 0; i < rgbMatrix.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rgbMatrix.cols; j++)
    {
       rgbMatrix.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = *value0;
       rgbMatrix.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = *value1;
       rgbMatrix.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = *value2;



    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<cv::Point3f> xyzBuffer;
cv::Mat xyzBuffMat = cv::Mat(307200, 1, CV_32FC3);
for (int i = 0; i < xyzBuffer.size(); i++) {
    xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 0) = xyzBuffer[i].x;
    xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 1) = xyzBuffer[i].y;
    xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 2) = xyzBuffer[i].z;
}
```

Here, 0, 1, and 2 are respectively the channels that store x, y and z values.