# Reading data cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I am looking for a better way to get data from a `cv::Mat 32F3C` , i was using this :
`Vec3f c1 = _image.at<Vec3f>(i,j);` it works fine, but not very quick, i saw that this way is better :

```
Vec3f c1(_image.data[step[0]*i + step[1]*j + 0],_image.data[step[0]*i + step[1]*j + 1],_image.data[step[0]*i + step[1]*j + 2]);
```

it compiles but it's not correct, i also tried this :

```
Vec3f c1(_image.data[step*i + channels*j + 0],_image.data[step*i + channels*j + 1],_image.data[step*i + channels*j + 2]);
```

but same thing, it compile but gives me an other absurd result.

I must be missing a factor or something.

Thanks !

Comment: DO you have debug turned off? There is an assertion check that can really slow things up. For random access, it is hard to beat at(). For sequential access see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way

Comment: It's saying : // accept only char type matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) in the OpenCV-Documentation useful. However, I would first write code that is easy to understand, and only optimize it, if it is apparent that I have to optimize exactly that portion of the source code.

The gist of the article is, that there are three methods for accessing the pixels:

1. On-the-fly address calculation:

   ```
   const cv::Vec3f& pixel = img.at< cv::Vec3f >(y, x)
   ```
2. Iterator:

   ```
   cv::MatIterator< cv::Vec3f > it=img.begin(), end=img.end();
   for ( ; it != end ; ++it ) (*it)[0] = (*it)[1]
   ```
3. Pointer:

   ```
   cv::Vec3f* pixel_ptr;
   for (int y = 0; y < img.rows; ++y)
   {
       pixel_ptr = img.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(y);
       for  (int x = 0; x < img.cols; ++x)
       {
           (*pixel_ptr)[0] = (*pixel_ptr)[1]
           ++pixel_ptr;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: isn't there a problem with col loop? where are you using x?

Comment: x is implicitly used to limit the number of "++pixel_ptr;" operations. DISCLAIMER: I have not used OpenCV or C++ for years and I have no idea if the examples above still work...

Answer (score 2):

You can surpass the at() function call and access the data of directly. Use cv::Mat::ptr (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) to get a pointer to the first element of every row of your image. Next you can access all the elements in that row using the array[index]-operator.

Image data is most of the time continuous in memory, but not always (think about selecting region of interest in another cv::Mat). You can find an example here: [OpenCV C++: how access pixel value CV_32F through uchar data pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569097/opencv-c-how-access-pixel-value-cv-32f-through-uchar-data-pointer). The image rows are continuous, which is why you ask a pointer to the first element in each iteration and can then safely access the other elements.

Comment: Channels are saved for each pixel consecutively, so that would mean that for each row you have to loop nbOfChannels * imageWidth times. Channel 1 of pixel 1 will be at dataPtr[0], channeld 2 of pixel 1 will be at dataPtr[1], channel 3 of pixel 1 at dataPtr[2] and, in your case, channel 1 of pixel 2 at dataPtr[3]. Typically that means adding an extra inner for loop that loops over all the channels. Example: Reed Richards answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387627/opencv-mat-class-accessing-elements-of-a-multi-channel-matrix

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the efficient way](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way)

```
cv::Mat _image = something;

for(int y = 0; y < _image.rows; ++y)
{
    cv::Vec3f* _image_row = _image.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(y);
    for(int x = 0; x< _image.cols; ++x)
    {
        cout << _image_row[x] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: this must be working, i tried this :
    for(int j=0; j<rows; j++){
   float* ptr1 = _image.ptr<float>(j);
   for(int i=0; i<cols*3; i+=3){          
       Vec3f c1 (ptr1[i],ptr1[i+1],ptr1[i+2]);
                std::cout << c1;
            }
    }      and it works fine

Comment: @user3883676 that's pretty much the same thing, except that since you construct a new  Vec3f instead of just pointing to the existing one, your code might be very slightly slower.